# Why meteor project update run endless?

Tags: meteor

I have installed meteor 1.4.1 and an older meteor project. If i try to update the project by running 'meteor update' 'Extracting templating@1.1.9...' runs endlessly. Does somebody has any idea what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Add `54.192.225.217 warehouse.meteor.com` to your host file, meteor reset and try again

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but what do you mean with "host file"?